# Method not found error in SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;    
import java.text.*;

public class GetPreviousAndNextDate
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        int MILLIS_IN_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;      
        Date date = new Date();       
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
        String prevDate = dateFormat.format(date.getTime() - MILLIS_IN_DAY);
        String currDate = dateFormat.format(date.getTime());
        String nextDate = dateFormat.format(date.getTime() + MILLIS_IN_DAY);

        System.out.println("Previous date: " + prevDate);
        System.out.println("Currnent date: " + currDate);
        System.out.println("Next date: " + nextDate);
    }  
}
```

i have this error

```
(Error(9,32): method format(long) not found in class java.text.SimpleDateFormat )
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code's logic is wrong. The results will be an hour off around the Daylight Savings Time switch, because that involves days that are 23 or 25 hours long.

For date arithmethic, you should always use the Calendar class:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    String prevDate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2);
    String nextDate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

(note that `Calendar.getTime()` returns a `Date` object and thereby fixes the type error as well)

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a date from a long you simply have to use the [new Date(long) API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)):

```
new Date(date.getTime() - MILLIS_IN_DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines use a method which doesn't exist:

```
 String prevDate = dateFormat.format(date.getTime() - MILLIS_IN_DAY);

 String currDate = dateFormat.format(date.getTime());

 String nextDate = dateFormat.format(date.getTime() + MILLIS_IN_DAY);
```

Method `format` accepts `Date` objects as parameters.

Try this:

```
 String prevDate = dateFormat.format(new Date(date.getTime() - MILLIS_IN_DAY));
```